# Google App Engine. Google app engine seeing POST requests as a GET

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, post, get

I'm having the strangest issue right now with google app engine. I'm sending a POST request from iOS and google app engine instead invokes the GET handler.

I've sandboxed this one situation for testing and can't get it figured out. I have an iOS app that just sends a request. And I've commented out everything on GAE except for the service. The service only logs a parameter and returns.

The iOS app I've tried using two different ways of sending the request. Neither works.

iOS Code:

```
/*
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://beermonster-gngrwzrd.appspot.com/TestParameter"];
ASIFormDataRequest * _fdrequest = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[_fdrequest setPostValue:@"hello" forKey:@"testkey"];
[_fdrequest startAsynchronous];
*/

NSURL * __url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://beermonster-gngrwzrd.appspot.com/TestParameter"];
NSMutableURLRequest * __request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:__url];
[__request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString * post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testkey=hello"];
[__request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:__request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

My App engine handler:

```
class TestParameter(webapp.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    logging.debug(self.request.get("testkey"))
    self.response.out.write(self.request.get("testkey"))
    print self.request.get("testkey")
def get(self):
    logging.debug("get")
    logging.debug(self.request.get("testkey"))
    self.response.out.write(self.request.get("testkey"))
```

The output in the GAE logs shows the "get" code path which isn't correct.

Any ideas why POST requests would come into GAE as a GET? Is there some configuration in GAE that I missed?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that there is a response to the POST that redirects to a GET?

Comment: not sure how that would happen or how to test that? I haven't directed it to do that. Is there a way to test that?

Comment: One way would be to use a packet sniffer on the wire to see what is *really* happening. This technique cuts through all the application level stuff that might be complicating the issue.

Comment: Ugh. yep looked at charles. If you hit a POST request on a non-secure attempt it sends back 302 redirect to the https version. Which is probably being resent as a get request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell if you want to send POST requests to GAE. Make sure you do it on https. If you make the request on a non-https attempt, it sends back a 302 redirect to the https version of the request. But if whatever you're using to send the request doesn't correctly handle 302's it might resend the request incorrectly.

Comment: This is incorrect. GAE can definitely receive a POST to a non-HTTPS handler. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the entry in app.yaml for the script that handles "/TestParameter". Does it specify "secure: always"? If it does and you make a non-secure connection you will get a 302 redirecting to the secure version.

To fix this either make your post over HTTPS or remove "secure: always" from the entry in app.yaml.